# Ng-admin: How to show different fields according to user's selection?

Tags: angularjs, ng-admin

I am using ng-admin to write a admin management. I met below issue, can somebody help me?

In my creationView, I would like to show different fields(text/video/pictures) according to the selection of "type" field. How I can make it?

```js
var articles = nga.entity('articles');
articles.creationView().fields([
      nga.field('type','choice')
            .validation({ required: true })
            .choices([
                // 1: txt, 2: pic, 3: vid
                { value: 1, label: 'Text'},
                { value: 2, label: 'Picture'},
                { value: 3, label: 'Video'},
            ]),
      nga.field('txt','file')
          .attributes({ placeholder: 'Write something... !' }),
      nga.field('pic','file')
          .label('Picture(.jpg|.png)')
          .uploadInformation({ 'url': '/api/adminapi/uploadPicture', 'apifilename': 'pictures', 'accept': 'image/jpg,image/png'}),
      nga.field('vid','file')
         .label('Video(.mp4)')
         .uploadInformation({ 'url': '/api/adminapi/uploadVideo', 'apifilename': 'video', 'accept': 'video/mp4'}),

])
```

Answer (score 5):

The [Field Configuration](https://github.com/marmelab/ng-admin/blob/master/doc/reference/Field.md) doc page explains how to do this using the "template" field config:

> **template(String|Function, templateIncludesLabel=false)** All field types
>   support the template() method, which makes it easy to customize the
>   look and feel of a particular field, without sacrificing the native
>   features.
>
> ...
>
> To force the template to replace the
>   entire line (including the label), pass true as second argument to the
>   template() call. This can be very useful to conditionally hide a field
>   according to a property of the entry:
>
> `post.editionView()
>       .fields([
>           nga.field('category', 'choice')
>               .choices([
>                   { label: 'Tech', value: 'tech' },
>                   { label: 'Lifestyle', value: 'lifestyle' }
>               ]),
>           nga.field('subcategory', 'choice')
>               .choices(function(entry) {
>                   return subCategories.filter(function (c) {
>                       return c.category === entry.values.category;
>                   });
>               })
>               // display subcategory only if there is a category
>               .template('<ma-field ng-if="entry.values.category" field="::field" value="entry.values[field.name()]" entry="entry"
>   entity="::entity" form="formController.form"
>   datastore="::formController.dataStore"></ma-field>', true),
>       ]);`

Answer (score 1):

I just have a work round method. That is using .attributes(onclick, "return updateButton();") for nga.field("type"). In updateButton() method, it will help to check current 'type' field value and using DOM methods to change the button enable and disabled.

However, I still realy appreciate that if this requirement can be support in future. It will be helpful for user to make UI controls easily.